# google maps infowindows is always attached to the first marker using ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, markers

i'm looping over an array to create markers and infowindows using **ionic** but the infowindow is always attached to the first marker

```html
 <map center="{{center_position.lat}},{{center_position.lng}}" zoom="15"  ng-repeat="mon_annonce in annonces">
        <marker ng-repeat="mon_annonce in annonces" 
            position="[{{mon_annonce.positionX}},{{mon_annonce.positionY}}]"
            title="{{mon_annonce.libelleAnnonce}}"
            visible="true">
        </marker>
        <info-window id="1" position="{{mon_annonce.positionX}},{{mon_annonce.positionY}}" visible="true">
          <div ng-non-bindable="">
            <b>{{mon_annonce.libelleAnnonce}}</b><br>
            {{mon_annonce.dateAnnonce}} <br>
          </div>
        </info-window>
      </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/56), we should not create each info-window for each marker.

> **When you click a maker, the instance of an InfoWindow will be created.
>   It's the same behaviour that Google Maps V3 api uses.**
>
> - It only breaks if you have an object with lat/long properties (rather than a simple array of arrays)
>
>   The following passed it as an array. Just a different format.
>
> [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KKS1tz4ub5hf8fKGapQ5?p=preview):
>
> ```
> <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="ng-scope">
>       <map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]">
>         <marker ng-repeat="p in positions" position="{{[p.0, p.1]}}" title="40.71,-74.21" class="ng-scope"
> ```
>
> on-click="showInfoWindow(event, 'marker-info')">
>             
>               [[this.getPosition()]]
>
> - The info window will not display if the markers are created with ng-repeat.
>
>   The markers ARE created with ng-repeat. An info-window is not created
>     as ng-repeat. and we should not create an info-window with ng-repeat.
>
> [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/E785zxnSZsxK2Ykjxwyr?p=preview):
>
> ```
> <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
>       <map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]">
>         <marker ng-repeat="p in positions" position="{{p}}" on-click="showInfoWindow(event, 'marker-info')"></marker>
>         <info-window id="marker-info">
>           <h4>Hi, my lat/lng is [[this.getPosition()]]</h4>
>         </info-window>
>       </map>
>     </div>
> ```

You can also create the info window on a click event to have full control of the info window. See this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eEE9tX4PlDstCeiQI6x2?p=preview).

Follow these tutorials:

- [Integrating Google Maps with an Ionic Application](http://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-google-maps-with-an-ionic-application/)
- [Implement Google Maps Using Ionic Framework](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/)
- [Best way to implement Google maps (and Places library) in Ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/best-way-to-implement-google-maps-and-places-library-in-ionic/16038/7)

Hope this helps!